# MapBox Navigation

Tags: android, mapbox

currently I'm stuck at creating a basic navigation for MapBox sdk. I've successfully able to view a map but unable to display the navigation function as I'm having a hard time finding any tutorial or easy to understand guide for the MapBox documentation, any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance. Here i include my Activity.

**ACTIVITY**

```
public class MapNavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, ProgressChangeListener, NavigationEventListener, MilestoneEventListener, OffRouteListener {

    private static final int BEGIN_ROUTE_MILESTONE = 1001;

    // Map variables
    @BindView(R.id.mapView)
    MapView mapView;

    @BindView(R.id.newLocationFab)
    FloatingActionButton newLocationFab;

    @BindView(R.id.startRouteButton)
    Button startRouteButton;

    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;

    // Navigation related variables
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private MapboxNavigation navigation;
    private DirectionsRoute route;
    private Position destination;
    private Position waypoint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_navigation);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        navigation = new MapboxNavigation(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        LocationEngine locationEngine = LostLocationEngine.getLocationEngine(this);
        navigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);

        // From Mapbox to The White House
        Position origin = Position.fromCoordinates(-77.03613, 38.90992);
        Position destination = Position.fromCoordinates(-77.0365, 38.8977);

        navigation.getRoute(origin, destination, 90f, new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(
                    Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        navigation.addNavigationEventListener(new NavigationEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRunning(boolean running) {

            }
        });
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.startRouteButton)
    public void onStartRouteClick() {
        if (navigation != null && route != null) {

            // Hide the start button
            startRouteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // Attach all of our navigation listeners.
            navigation.addNavigationEventListener(this);
            navigation.addProgressChangeListener(this);
            navigation.addMilestoneEventListener(this);

            ((MockLocationEngine) locationEngine).setRoute(route);
            navigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
            navigation.startNavigation(route);
            mapboxMap.setOnMapClickListener(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Remove all navigation listeners being used
        navigation.removeNavigationEventListener(this);
        navigation.removeNavigationEventListener(this);
        navigation.removeProgressChangeListener(this);
        navigation.removeOffRouteListener(this);

        // End the navigation session
        navigation.endNavigation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
        navigation.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRunning(boolean running) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMilestoneEvent(RouteProgress routeProgress, String instruction, int identifier) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress routeProgress) {

    }

    @Override
    public void userOffRoute(Location location) {

    }
}
```

Comment: // See This Link MapBox With NAvigation ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199033/show-navigation-view-of-mapbox-with-direction-units-km-minutes-instead-of-miles/49941591#49941591

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the an official tutorial on *Building a navigation app for Android*.
https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-navigation-sdk/

It explains these items:

- Install the Navigation SDK
- Initialize a map
- Display user location
- Add a marker on click
- Calculate and draw route
- Add a button to start navigation
- Customize the style

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer that might be useful to someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

After intensive research around the web, I've finally able to make my navigation working. So I'm gonna share with you all the source for my reference that enable my navigation apps.

[NavHud Mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-hud-demo)